# Change the text color of a textfield if range exceeds certain number

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

i want to dynamically change the color of my text depending if it exceeds a certain range of numbers (between 0 and 360). i will share my code that is currently working but not changing colors.

```
class _DurationContainers extends StatelessWidget {
  const _DurationContainers({
    Key? key,
    required this.controller, required this.hint, required this.digits,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String hint;
  final TextEditingController controller;
  final int digits;


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Neumorphic(
      style: marketplaceButtonsNeuStyle.copyWith(
           boxShape: NeumorphicBoxShape.roundRect(BorderRadius.circular(15))
        ),
      child: Container(
        width: ScreenUtils.percentWidth(context, 3.2),
        child: TextFormField(
          
          controller: controller,
          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
          textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
          onSaved: (precio) {},
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          cursorColor: Color.fromARGB(148, 66, 63, 63) ,
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline1!.copyWith(fontSize: 20),
          inputFormatters: [
          LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(digits),
          FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
         
          ],
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            border: InputBorder.none,
            hintStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline1!.copyWith(fontSize: 21),
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: ScreenUtils.percentHeight(context, .5)),
            hintText: hint
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have tried parsing the data from my textfield to an int and setting a limit but i think im not doing it correctly since its giving me errors.

This is what im currently trying to do.

[image: Text is normal since is between the range of 0 and 360]

[image: Text should turn red once exceeding the max range of 360 turning red]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Can set a condition for the colour in style.

[image]

To avoid an error you can set the value of the variable and update it.

Comment: For some reason whenever i use int.parse i get format exception error

Comment: @Arisbor you need to enter only number to the textField, otherwise it will going to throw error when parse it to int.  You can set keyboardType parameter of textField to TextInputType.number

Comment: @TimurTurbil it gives me the error before the textfield even forms, i even set an initial value for the field as "0", but the widget just wont form if i use int.parse

Comment: If `controller.text` is empty `int.parse` throws error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `StatefulWidget` and `onChanged` callback from `TextFormField`.

```
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyWidget> createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  final controller = TextEditingController();
  bool isValid = true;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(
        child: SizedBox(
            width: 100,
            child: TextFormField(
              onChanged: (value) {
                isValid = int.parse(value) < 360;
                setState(() {});
              },
              maxLength: 3,
              controller: controller,
              keyboardType:
                  const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
              style: TextStyle(color: isValid ? null : Colors.red),
            )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```